# Android AdapterView - Children not getting proper size after view.layout() is called

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am building a custom AdapterView layout for my application. So far I am able to position all the item according to my specs. The only problem is that all the children still have getMeasuredWith == screen width. So after calling the layout() method for each child and defining its new width, all the children from this view keep the same size as before.

What do I need to do in order to get all the children view from my View to keep their bound between each child view.

Thanks
Thiago

Answer (score 0):

To reliably get the size that your view needs to be you have to override the [onSizeChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method.